# Oracle/SQL - Update a Column with Results from Subquery/Other Table [Multiple Returns]

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to update the “p_outbound_comments” table

[image]

So that the “creator” column populates itself with the corresponding “car_move_id” from p_shipping_view where the ordnum matches.

I’m using this query:

`UPDATE p_outbound_comments t1
   SET (creator) = (SELECT t2.car_move_id
                      FROM p_shipping_view t2
                     WHERE t1.ordnum = t2.ordnum)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM p_shipping_view t2
               WHERE t1.ordnum = t2.ordnum)`

Problem is that the inner query for the SET returns the car_move_id’s for all of the ord nums that match. Because of this, I get an oracle error as the inner query returns more than one result.

How can I update each rows “creator” column succsessfuly with the “car_move_id” from p_shipping_view where the ordnum’s match all in one go?

Comment: You have to choose one of them.  One possibility is to just add `where rownum = 1` to the first subquery.

Comment: Well, thats the thing, the two that are returned are correct. They are the two car_move_id's that need to be assigned to their respective row in p_outbound_comments. (in the creator field)

Comment: (based on the ordnum matching)

Comment: Yes, but you only can assign one value to one row, i think there is no way to do that

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm confusing people. I only want it to assign one value to one row. The two fields that have 'creator' blank above need their respective 'car_move_id' from p_shipping_view where the ordnums match on both tables. I need the update to update for all of the NULL creator rows. (If car_move_id is null in the other table as-well then don't update.)

Comment: Because null is not equal to null in plsql, don't worry about these records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) is suitable for this task:

```
MERGE INTO p_outbound_comments D
  USING (
    SELECT car_move_id, ordnum
      FROM p_shipping_view
      WHERE car_move_id IS NOT NULL
  ) S ON (D.ordnum = S.ordnum)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET D.creator = S.car_move_id
    WHERE D.creator IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If the subquery returns the same value but multiple records you can basically use one of the following in your subquery

select distinct t2.car_mive_ID
select max (t2.car_move_ID)
select min (t2.car_movr_ID)
select avg(t2.car_move_ID)